# Avoid re-resolving conflicts in a git rebase including merge commits

Tags: git, rebase, merge-conflict-resolution

Trying to move history from one repo to another (no common root) by adding the source remote and rebasing to a branch on the local destination repo.

Source:

```
A-B-C
 \ /
  E
```

Wanted on destination:

```
F-A'-B'-C'
   \   /
     E'
```

Documentation for git rebase --rebase-merges says it will preserve topology and re-create merge commits, but:

> Any resolved merge conflicts or manual amendments in these merge commits will have to be resolved/re-applied manually.

Now, I want to avoid re-resolving conflicts and I am puzzled why this is needed at all. The content of the merge commit is there, I can detach HEAD to to.

So, I tried

```
$ git rebase -i --onto destnewbranch --root --rebase-merges srcbranch
Could not apply C... master # Merge branch 'master'

(detached HEAD|REBASE x/y)
$ git status
interactive rebase in progress; onto F
Last commands done (n commands done):
   pick B
   merge -C C master # Merge branch 'master' 

You have unmerged paths.
  (fix conflicts and run "git commit")
  (use "git merge --abort" to abort the merge)
```

To solve conflicts, I am taking the content of C:

```
$ git reset --hard C
```

Now content is good but history is not, so:

```
$ git reset --soft HEAD@{1}
```

All is there is left to do is to move on with the rebase:

```
$ git commit
$ git rebase --continue
```

However, history is wrong since I am left with:

```
F-A'-B'-C'
```

So C' is not a merge commit, although it has the resolved changes of both B and E.
Merge commits that don't cause conflict are successfully rebased with the topology intact.

I think it is me who is messing up the the MERGING state of the rebase by resetting and the final git commit will NOT create a merge commit, but a regular one. If I don't do the resets and resolve the conflicts manually, git commit will create a merge commit.

git version 2.26.0.windows.1

Comment: this usually happens when 2 branches' history diverges (usually due to a rebase) and ends up with the same changes in different diffs.  I just did this myself, pushed it, and facepalmed, a few days ago.  Then had to rebase again and fix the conflicts on every subsequent commit.  I don't know a better solution, but looking forward to seeing what the group comes up with.

Answer (score 3):

To resolve a conflict using the contents of an existing commit, use `git restore`. Do not use `git reset --hard` which modifies `HEAD`.

However even that doesn't work in most cases. What you are probably looking for is called `rerere` (short for "reuse recorded resolutions"). Enable it in the Git configuration:

```
git config rerere.enabled true
```

When it is enabled, it will record all resolved conflicts, allowing to replay them later. To automatically stage these recorded conflicts, you can also set `rerere.autoupdate`:

```
git config rerere.autoupdate true
```

Additionally, you can teach `rerere` about past merges and resolved conflict using the `rerere-train.sh` script which is often distributed with Git (on Ubuntu it is available at `/usr/share/doc/git/contrib/rerere-train.sh`). Call it before rebasing to avoid having to redo any previously resolved conflicts:

```
rerere-train.sh destnewbranch..srcbranch
git rebase destnewbranch srcbranch --onto destnewbranch --rebase-merges
```

Comment: Tried git restore instead of git reset. It unfortunately gets rid of changes in F at every conflicted merge. Since I only had one file added in F, I restored that from F, just so I can continue...

Comment: ...  I hit a roadblock with submodules however. Command git restore --source C -- . does not bring changes to submodule HEAD, no matter --recurse-submodules. I noticed it picking the next the commit immediately after C (I have more than the simplified example here) and rebase conflicted on the submodule. Tried git checkout --theirs submodule and ended up with $ git submodule status
U0000000000000000000000000000000000000000. Fail.

Comment: Tried rerere too... During rerere-train.sh I am having issues with binary files: warning: Cannot merge binary files: system.hdf (ours vs. theirs)
error: could not parse conflict hunks in 'system.hdf'. No surprise that these binary files do not get automatically resolved during the rebase merge. All in all, this is a giant fail.

Comment: `rerere`, like most other git features, doesn't support binary files. I believe there no easy way to automatically re-resolve conflicts in binary files. Perhaps you can avoid rebasing and use `git merge --allow-unrelated-histories` instead?

Comment: Was trying to avoid git merge --allow-unrelated-histories, but it seems to be the most accesible solution.